# How to install a JavaScript editor for Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a standard Eclipse running on an Ubuntu 14.10:

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
```

1. I searched for `javascript` in the marketplace. But nothing jumped to my eye.
2. I searched `javascript editor eclipse` on the web, which gave me `JSDT` (https://eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) But I couldn't find it in the marketplace.
3. I realised, that `JSDT` are budled within the `WDT` (Web Tools Platform; https://eclipse.org/webtools/).

It seems that I'm lacking some basic knowledge about eclipse.

- Is it somehow possible to install `JSDT` without all the other stuff of the `WTP`?
- When I'd like to use `WTP`, do I need a separate installation of Eclipse? (since `WTP` is also not in the marketplace)
- Is there an JavaScript editor plugin that I can simply add to my existing Eclipse installation?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can install all or part of Eclipse WTP in to your current Eclipse.

To install just JSDT open 'Help > Install New Software...'.

In "Work with" choose your main Eclipse site (`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna` for Eclipse Luna).

Expand the 'Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development' section and select 'JavaScript Development Tools'

Click Next> to proceed with the install.

Comment: That worked, thanks. But why is it not shown in the Marketplace? When I go to http://marketplace.eclipse.org, the title says "Eclipse Plugins, Bundles and Products - Eclipse Marketplace". I expected to find the JSDT there. So Why is it not in the marketplace?

Comment: Marketplace is a relatively new addition to Eclipse. The main Eclipse projects use the older Install New Software system for installs.

Comment: I don't know why my Luna version doesn't have this option? Here's the screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/53k6tue81/. I don't see "JavaScript Development Tools". Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: @SSun Possibly it is already installed and you have 'Hide items that are already installed' checked.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your response. But I just checked my installed software: http://postimg.org/image/am437yy2p/, it's not there either. :(

Answer (score 3):

Refer this answer -> [Javascript file editing stopped working with Eclipse 2020-06](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742955/javascript-file-editing-stopped-working-with-eclipse-2020-06)

The Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers is made up of components from various Eclipse projects. In the Eclipse IDE 2020-06 release the JavaScript support for .js file is no longer provided by the JavaScript editor from JSDT, but by Eclipse Wild Web Developer.

Wild Web Developer does not provide a separate Editor for JavaScript, but extends the Generic Text Editor by code completion, syntax highlighting, validation, navigation, etc. for JavaScript.

To get back the JSDT JavaScript editor you have to uninstall Eclipse Wild Web Developer and install JavaScript Development Tools from the Eclipse IDE 2020-03 release (I guess the problems if you had both were solved by simply removing or disabling the JavaScript editor in the 2020-06 release):

Uninstall Eclipse Wild Web Developer: In Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details, in the Installed Software tab select Eclipse Wild Web Developer and click Uninstall...
Install JavaScript Development Tools from the 2020-03 release: In Help > Install New Software... work with https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03 and choose JavaScript Development Tools to install

Comment: Thankyou for sorting this out for us.  The Wild Web Developer rendering for a Javascript editor was very annoying..

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to JSDT is to install the Wild Web Developer plugin from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bluesky-web-development-eclipse-ide-experimental . It's using the latest Language Server for HTML, CSS, JSON, JavaScript and TypeScript. It's open-source and is becoming an official Eclipse.org project.