# Javascript file editing stopped working with Eclipse 2020-06

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-2020-06

I have been working on the exact same file directory with eclipse for many years. It just worked. I am using PHP, CSS, JS, HTML files.

Occasionally, I ran an automatic upgrade as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades). This also just worked.

Now after the latest upgrade, several things just *stopped* working:

- In PHP files, the core commands are not auto-completed anymore. I searched for a solution, to no avail.
- Javascript files don't get any special editor anymore.

Now my most pressing question is:

**Where do I re-enable the good old Javascript editor?**

Here's my Installation details:
[image]

Comment: Apparently the Javascript editor was just dropped with no proper announcement. The Wild Web Developer code is supposed to be a replacement. See [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564496)

Comment: What a catch, @greg-449! Thank you, and this is indeed unbelievable news - just like the users express it on that bug! I'll keep this question up just so it might get some new answers as this apparently new situation evolves.

Comment: There was a statement of sorts, https://www.eclipse.org/lists/wtp-dev/msg10917.html, but not from anyone recognized from JSDT's vaunted 2.0 reboot. They also haven't been shy about injecting remarks evangelizing Wild Web Developer into bug reports on the existing tools.

Comment: @greg-449 There was a bug report where this change was discussed before and afterwards it was mentioned in the New & Noteworthy. Where and how should a proper announcement have been made in this case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers* is made up of components from various Eclipse projects. In the **Eclipse IDE 2020-06** release the **JavaScript support** for `.js` file is **no longer** provided by the JavaScript editor from [***JSDT***](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/), but by [***Eclipse Wild Web Developer***](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper).

***Wild Web Developer*** does **not** provide a **separate Editor** for JavaScript, but **extends** the **Generic Text Editor** by code completion, syntax highlighting, validation, navigation, etc. **for JavaScript**.

To **get back the JSDT JavaScript editor** you have to **uninstall *Eclipse Wild Web Developer*** and **install *JavaScript Development Tools*** from the Eclipse IDE **2020-03** release (I guess the problems if you had both were solved by simply removing or disabling the JavaScript editor in the 2020-06 release):

1. **Uninstall *Eclipse Wild Web Developer***: In ***Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details***, in the *Installed Software* tab select *Eclipse Wild Web Developer* and click ***Uninstall...***
2. **Install *JavaScript Development Tools*** from the **2020-03** release: In ***Help > Install New Software...*** work with [**`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03`**](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03) and choose ***JavaScript Development Tools*** to install

See also [Eclipse IDE 2020-06](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/2020-06/) > [New & Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/2020-06/noteworthy/) > [Eclipse PHP Development Tools](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/NewIn72)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! As described in the question, the real issue is probably in the fact that I did an automatic upgrade. It did *not* install the "Wild Web Developer" automatically. I added it manually and it seems to work for now - though I am surprised by the bugs I noticed immediately - and hope there won't be many more to come...

Comment: Like @SwissMister, the upgrade did not install "Wild Web Developer" for me.  Installing it did not help me either, as it apparently has some serious pre-reqs I didn't want to install.  Instead, I had to uninstall the remnants of my now defunct version of "JavaScript Development Tools" using step 1 above and then reinstall the older version using step 2.  Hope this info helps someone else!

Comment: @JonWeers Does the upgrade to Eclipse 2020-09 (that will be released today in a couple of hours) install _Wild Web Developer_ for you? The new version has Node.js embedded to run the language server for the JavaScript support, so no pre-reqs to install (see [my video](https://youtu.be/-qsW-0Ztg_U?t=568)).

Comment: Also noteworthy - the Generic Editor file association works to apply JS syntax highlighting for Wild Web Developer for *newly opened JS files*. If you have one open and, like me, were expecting to see the lovely colors magically appear, you'll need to close and reopen.

Comment: Thank you. I needed this to apply my old formatter for js files.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, using 2020-09. I found that *Wild Web Developer* (in ***Help > Eclipse Marketplace..***) was indeed installed, but then I checked *more info* and it said

> To see it in action, open the desired file with the Generic Editor that's included by default in the Eclipse IDE.

and when I opened the javascript file in the Generic Editor, I get all the fancy I need...

Comment: It's not an answer.Please use comments

Comment: @V.Tur Yes... sorry, my bad. Didn't notice the "Add Comment" button. "better luck next time", eh?

Answer (score 0):

go to **Window -> Preferences** then type **file associations** then select ***.js** on the right side list, then select **"Generic Text Editor"** below and click **"Default"** button

Comment: Thank you for sharing the idea! It does not treat anything about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes versions above 2020-05 works with General Editor as default editor for JS files in eclipse

Window--> Preferences --> File Associations --> Select (*.js) and then select Generic Editor

[image: Screenshot of the menu]