# How can I find JavaScript project option in Eclipse 2020-06?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have downloaded **Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers** package of **2020-06** version. But while creating project I am not seeing "JavaScript Project" option upon doing "File >> New". Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: @GetSet I am not quite following you. Could you please explain a bit more on this please?

Comment: Answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62756966/6505250

Answer (score 1):

As of that release, you no longer need a distinct JavaScript Project and its associated Include Path and other options, as JavaScript support is primarily coming from the [Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/) project. WWD provides features to the Generic Editor, and doesn't place any requirements on the file to be in a particular folder in a special kind of project. Ideally, you just create a JavaScript file and start coding without needing to tell Eclipse anything about your project that you're not already setting up otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to create a Static Web Project, I recommend:

- double check your installed software - do you have all the sub-packages for Web Development?
- take a look at the [CodeMix](https://www.genuitec.com/products/codemix/) project (also installable through the Eclipse market place) - its a commercial product but may have what you need in there.

Comment: What does [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) (which is now built-in) have that the commercial product you advertise does not have (except the bugs, high CPU, memory and disk space usage and that it spies on you)?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked:

To get back the **JSDT JavaScript editor** you have to uninstall **Eclipse Wild Web Developer** and install **JavaScript Development Tools** from the Eclipse IDE 2020-03 release.

**Uninstall Eclipse Wild Web Developer**: In Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details, in the Installed Software tab select Eclipse Wild Web Developer and click Uninstall

**Install JavaScript Development Tools from the 2020-03 release**: In Help > Install New Software... work with https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03 and choose JavaScript Development Tools to install

Comment: This worked for me, too.  After spending a few hours trying to get Wild Web Developer working (I couldn't even get it to do syntax highlighting, and I was using the generic text editor as suggested), I decided that I had actual work to get done and reinstalled the JavaScript Development tools from 2020-03.  I'm sure WWD is a fine project, but rolling it out as an eclipse update without at least providing clear instructions about getting it to work seems like bad development practice.  I just don't have time to learn Eclipse development in order to get this working.